# Delete file if its name starts with a date older than the current one (Google Drive)

Tags: google-apps-script

With help from the Stackoverflow community, I was able to create this script that deletes files that are over 3 hours old:

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 3 Hours
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()}); // Modified
  }
  obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a= new Date(a.date).valueOf();
    var b= new Date(b.date).valueOf();
    return b-a;
  });
  obj.shift();
  return obj; // Modified
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var email = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"; // Added
  var obj = getOldFileIDs(); // Modified
  obj.forEach(function(e) { // Modified
    if (e.owner == email) { // Added
      Drive.Files.remove(e.id); // Modified
    }
  });
};
```

File names in this folder always start with a date, such as:

`2019/10/05 SerieA Vasco da Gama x Flamengo.pdf`

I would like a help to know what I need to modify in the script and what it would look like so that instead of deleting when it has more than 3 hours of creation, it from it files that have a date earlier than the current.

I tried to modify `.getdate` but it was totally unsuccessful, I couldn't make the script parse the beginning of the file name, I could only find the file name and its id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are the files with the filename like `2019/10/05 SerieA Vasco da Gama x Flamengo.pdf`.

  - The date string and the format are always 10 characters from the top of the filename and `yyyy/MM/dd`, respectively.
- You want to delete the files which has old date string in the filename before the today.

  - In this case, `more than 3 hours of creation` is ignored. So `modifiedDate` is also ignored.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers. The flow of this modified script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve all files in the folder.
2. For each file, retrieve the filename and the date string.
3. Convert the date string in the filename to the date object. And it is compared with today. When the date in the filename is older than today, the file information is added to the array for deleting.
4. Delete the files from the retrieved file information

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify the function of `getOldFileIDs()` as follows.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var today = new Date(new Date().toDateString()).getTime();
  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var dateFromFilename = file.getName().substr(0, 10);
    if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) { // Here, the format of date string is checked.
      var date = new Date(dateFromFilename).getTime();
      if (date < today) {
        obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()});
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

#### References:

- [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.